# Report Viewer Parameters not being set programmatically

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

Hello,
I'm trying to use Report Viewer Control in ASPX page to load some SSRS reports i have.

So far I'm facing problem with setting the data source and parameter values.

I need to set the data source credentials of the report, and an internal/hidden parameter for the report, in addition to the parameters that have to be filled in by the user.

This is the code I'm using in the Page_Load method:

```
 DataSourceCredentials dsCredentials = new DataSourceCredentials()
        {
            Name = dsProps.Name,
            UserId = dsProps.Username,
            Password = dsProps.Password
        };

        // Configure properties of report viewer
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(rsProps.ReportServerURL);
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = rsProps.ReportPath;


        // Assign given parameters
        ReportParameter[] reportParams = new ReportParameter[parameters.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++)
            reportParams[i] = new ReportParameter(parameters.ElementAt(i).Key, parameters.ElementAt(i).Value);
        if (reportParams.Length > 0)
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParams);
         ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(new DataSourceCredentials[] { dsCredentials });
```

So far, the viewer, upon loading, still prompts the user for the data source credentials, and issues an error that the internal/hidden parameters are missing a value, as if my settings in code have no effect.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

I found that before I could set the parameters (SetParameter) I had to set the ReportServerCredentials.  That's 2 hours I'll never get back.

Comment: Save my time, Set Parameter place after ReportServer credentails

Answer (score 1):

I believe i fixed the problem.

I was impersonating a specific windows user for this code, and when i had impersonation code  i set parameters and data source it was failing and not taking the values.

I moved impersonation before the mentioned code and it worked ,so far at least.